# Record triggering Flow using old value when filtering a get record

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I have a flow that is set to run after the record is saved to the database.
The field that triggers the start of the flow is a change on the 'Billing State'.

I want to get an element using the **new** Billing State value as the condition but the value I'm seeing is the old Billing State Value.

[image]

As you can see here, the BillingStateCode was in fact changed. From ND(North Dakota) to NY(New York), BUT when using the BillingState as a condition, it is still using North Dakota.

Comment: I just tested in a sandbox by creating an after-update record-triggered Flow. I confirmed that when I debug by changing the `BillingState` from "FL" to DE", I see that the `$Record.BillingState` is still "FL" but the `$Record.BillingStateCode` is "DE".

Comment: And [every](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/296868/81648) [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/288615/81648) I find on SFSE indicates that that behavior is expected in a BEFORE trigger, but not an AFTER. But I found nothing specific on a Flow rather than Apex.

Comment: Which does not make sense to me because the most recent version of the [Order of Execution diagram](https://architect.salesforce.com/1/asset/immutable/s/e6cf2ac/assets/images/Salesforce-Order-Of-Execution-Diagram.png) shows that AFTER TRIGGERS are Step 8 and AFTER SAVE FLOWS are Step 14. So if the triggers see it correctly, it seems to me that the Flows should, too. Unless something wonky and unexpected occurs in Steps 9 through 13....

Comment: once one moves to state and country picklists, I find it is more reliable to always work with the `xxxCode` fields for logic and filters

Comment: fwiw there is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003esWQAQ) about this behavior in terms of before trigger context with the workaround being to use the Code version of the fields as cropredy noted. Is this behavior only occurring in flow debug mode (or actually affecting real record updates)? Definitely worth a case to confirm if flows have a different limitation here than apex.

Comment: I did a little more testing, and it is very weird. If I use `$Record.BillingState` on a GET RECORDS inside the Flow, it uses the prior value even outside of debug & doesn't find records. However, if within the Flow I use the value of `$Record.BillingState` to update a random text field on some record, in debug it shows that it is populating with the prior value; but when activated & run in the org, it populates with the correct value. So it seems that somehow while the Flow is running the `State` field has not yet correctly been updated, but by the time the Flow ends it has the correct value.

Comment: Methinks, *ErFran*, that thou foundst a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This help article's last bullet explains why it could still be wrong in debug mode.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_troubleshooting.htm&type=5

> When you debug a record-triggered flow, only what’s within the flow is tested. This smaller scope can lead to scenarios where the flow executes as intended while debugging, but not at runtime. This behavior difference can be due to other triggered flows and processes. To see how a record-triggered flow behaves in a real-world scenario, make sure to test it in a sandbox org.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.